# Simulink output start time

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm doing a control simulation, and my output needs to start at 0.1 but instead it always starts at 0 as I show below. My graph should look like the following but instead it starts at 0.

Is there any solution?

Simulink Diagram:
[image: Simulink Diagram]

Scope of the Diagram:
[image: Scope of the Diagram]

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want.  Do you want a) the same axis scalings and signal but with nothing drawn between 0 and 0.1, or b) the x-axis starting at 0.1 with the signal starting at 0.035 (approx.), or c) the same axis scaling but the signal delayed by 0.1, or d) the x-axis starting at 0.1 with the signal starting at 0, or e) something else?

Comment: @PhilGoddard my output needs to start at 0.1 and gets to steady state at 0.11. this is how my plot needs to look like : [link](http://imgur.com/a/b5qDL)

Comment: So you need to set the intial states of the appropriate blocks - most likely just the integrators -- correctly so that the signal being viewed matches your required image.